# count consecutive repeats of values

Tags: matlab, find

I have a dataset, which normally has data every half hour (so 2 data per hour), BUT some data have 3 data per hour, and I want the 3rd one removed. So, for every hour, I want to see how many times that is repeated consecutively.

Simplified example:

A= [0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 **4 4 4** 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 **7 7 7** 8 8 9 9 10 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 11 12 12 13 13 **14 14 14** 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23 ...]

I want to know what the coordinates are of the bold **4, 7** and **14**, since they are repeated consecutively three times in stead of two.
This is the code I wrote, but it only outputs the Nan matrix and does not fill it with the coordinates I am looking for.

```
indexes=year(P20102330.Date)==Year & month(P20102330.Date)==Month; % select correct data from dataset
Feb2330=P20102330(indexes,:);

for i=1:24
    vindhours=find(hour(Feb2330.Date)==i-1);%find coordinates, one hour per step
    svindhours=numel(vindhours); 
    blob=[];
    for j =1:svindhours-1
        result=nan(24,svindhours);%make nan matrix
        if vindhours(j)-vindhours(j+1)==1 %find the coordinates which only differ by one (are consequetive)
            blob=[blob, j] % add those coordinates to a vector
            if numel(blob)>2 % if they are repeated more than 2 times, add them to the result matrix
                result(i,j)=vindhours(j)
            end 
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: 1) So what should the result be, exactly, in your example? An array of coordinates of the start of each run? 2) There's a run of three fours starting at position 103; shouldn't that be detected too? 3) Should a run of four or six equal values be detected as a single run, or as two runs of three values? That is, what's the output for [1 2 2 4 4 4 4 5 6 6 6 6 6 6]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood, you don't need to loop, you can just check if each element of the array matches the following two elements of the same array:

```
A = [0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23];
n = numel(A);
rep3 = A(1:(n-2))==A(2:(n-1)) & A(1:(n-2))==A(3:n);
hrs = A(rep3)
```

In the input the 4s are repeated on two occasions, and so appears twice:

```
hrs =

     4     7     4    14
```

If you want unique values, then use the `unique` function...

Comment: This works! To find the coordinates, `rep3` should be `rep3= find(A(1:(n-2))==A(2:(n-1)) & A(1:(n-2))==A(3:n));`